# Cannot failover an availability replica for availability group since it has CLUSTER_TYPE = NONE

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

Using SQL Server 2017, when I try to manually failover AG to the secondary node by using Failover wizard in SSMS, I got following error

**Cannot failover an availability replica for availability group since it has CLUSTER_TYPE = NONE. Only force failover is supported in this version of SQL Server. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 47122)**

Failover Readiness shows "No data loss" and I used Automatic seeding to initialize the database on secondary, Readable secondary is set to yes on the secondary.

When I tried manual failover on the secondary the status of AG is not Synchronizing with the following warning:

**The data synchronization state of this availability database is unhealthy. On an asynchronous-commit availability replica, every availability database should be in the SYNCHRONIZING state.**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which Cumulative Update are you running on 2017? From ~ CU 11 (I don't remember specifically) you need to explicitly add `FORCE_FAILOVER_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS` to your failover command because it's emphasizing to you that data loss is possible.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise 2017 (RTM-CU16), but still have the issue.